# How to fix the Authlogic Heroku Can't Logout Issue in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I followed the Railscasts on using Authlogic and it works perfect locally in the development environment but when I push to Heroku, I cannot logout. I read that using an Active Record session works but I also read that it's not advised for large traffic sites. I'm not using Passenger. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Can you place here your heroku link? and btw what version of rails and  Authlogic are you using? Please provide details in the question.