# Heroku hosted site can't log out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been working my way through the Hartl tutorial and some railscasts in order to learn RoR.  After implementing the railscast "remember password" check box I can no longer log out of my example user on the Heroku hosted site.  Everything works beautifully locally, but on Heroku, if I try to sign it, flash will tell me that I've successfully logged out, but nothing has actually happened.  The problem persists even after db migration.  I think my problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338870/how-to-fix-the-authlogic-heroku-cant-logout-issue-in-production), but I see that no one has answered that question.  Does anyone have any ideas?  I'm using the `bcrypt-ruby` gem (version 3.0.1).

My `sign_in` action in my sessions helper looks like this:

```
def sign_in(user)
  if params[:remember_me]
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  else
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
  self.current_user = user
end
```

And my `sign_out` action looks like this:

```
def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

@abhir - I think these are the relevant bits from the log:

```
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/signout" for 108.228.60.12 at 2013-04-04 14:13:34 +0000
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"<TOKENWASHERE>"}
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://quiet-spire-8115.herokuapp.com/
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/signout host=quiet-spire-8115.herokuapp.com fwd="108.228.60.12" connect=11ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=105
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 108.228.60.12 at 2013-04-04 14:13:34 +0000
2013-04-04T14:13:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
```

As you can see, the site is [here](https://quiet-spire-8115.herokuapp.com/).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post some results from your `heroku logs` on signout? Do you also have a link to the heroku site?

Comment: Looks like your cookies ware not updated properly.  Also, in the sign_out method I see no flash message.

Comment: @taro - Thanks for the suggestion!  I deleted the cookie, but it didn't seem to fix the problem.  Also, the flash message is in the controller (not the helper) and seems to be working fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, here is the fix. The only problem with this fix is that you can't stay logged in as user/1. However, it works fine for everyone else. Essentially, heroku is associating not having a cookie with user/1. At least that was the way I understood that it was explained to me.

Try changing your current user method in our sessions helper to this:

```
def current_user
    if cookies[:remember_token].present?
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

end

Comment: that seems to have done it!  Thanks!  I don't really understand why user #1 wouldn't be able to have a cookie, but it seems to be working!